# Pass the Multiple quotes around @variable wherever single quote is there

Tags: sql, sql-server

Below is my procedure. It is working fine.

```
Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[spCompanyName]              
(              
  @CompanyName VARCHAR(100))
  AS
  Begin

  DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX) 
  SET @sql =  ' Select EmpID,CompanyName FROM Employee' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)  

  IF len(@CompanyName) > 0               
    BEGIN              
        SET @sql = @sql + ' Where (RTRIM(LTRIM(CompanyName)) like ''' + @CompanyName + '%'') ' + char(13) + char(10)      
    END 

    PRINT @SQL  
    EXEC(@sql)  
End

exec spCompanyName @CompanyName='So Unique, formerly Sofia''''s'
```

I need Wherever single quote is there in companyname,if I pass 8 quotes in single quotes I need output.above procedure where do I need to change.

Eg:

```
exec spCompanyName @CompanyName='So Unique, formerly Sofia''''''''s'

exec spCompanyName @CompanyName='Absolute''''''''s,Strategy''''''''s'
```

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. That code is product specific.

Comment: It's always nice if you have a stored procedure which does not assume you know about it's inner workings. In this case, you should be able to just pass your company name as is, and add the quotes inside your proc. Passing extra quotes because *you* know the proc uses dynamic SQL isn't advisable.

Comment: can you tell me the where do I need to change

Comment: This is not "SQL", which DBMS are you using?

Comment: SQL Server 2012

Answer (score 0):

Don't think "I'll throw away all of the useful features of using parameters to separate *data* from *code* and start manually trying to protect strings" - keep using parameters.

Rather than

```
EXEC(@sql)
```

Have:

```
EXEC sp_executesql @sql,N'@CompanyName varchar(100)',@CompanyName = @CompanyName
```

And change:

```
SET @sql = @sql + ' Where (RTRIM(LTRIM(CompanyName)) like ''' + @CompanyName + '%'') ' + char(13) + char(10)
```

to:

```
SET @sql = @sql + ' Where (RTRIM(LTRIM(CompanyName)) like @CompanyName + ''%'') ' + char(13) + char(10)
```

---

Or, in the alternative, consider just writing a normal query, no dynamic SQL:

```
Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[spCompanyName]              
(              
  @CompanyName VARCHAR(100))
WITH RECOMPILE
  AS
  Begin

  Select EmpID,CompanyName FROM Employee
  Where RTRIM(LTRIM(CompanyName)) like @CompanyName + '%' or
        @CompanyName is null
End
```

Assuming you're using SQL Server 2008 (with particular patch levels) or later, as specified in Erland Sommarskog's [Dynamic Search Conditions in T-SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search-2008.html)

Comment: It shows the below   error       Select EmpID,CompanyName FROM Employee
 Where (RTRIM(LTRIM(CompanyName)) like @CompanyName + '%') 
Msg 214, Level 16, State 2, Procedure sp_executesql, Line 1
Procedure expects parameter '@statement' of type 'ntext/nchar/nvarchar'.

Comment: No I want to do this in production side. So I need dynamic way.

Comment: @Malyadri - ah, forgot, you need to change the declaration of `@sql` to be an `nvarchar` rather than `varchar`.

Comment: Alter PROCEDURE [dbo].[spCompanyName]              
(              
  @CompanyName VARCHAR(100))
  AS
  Begin

Comment: it shows empty records after changing nvarchar in SQL string

Comment: I have exec Proc  exec spCompanyName @CompanyName='So Unique, formerly Sofia''''''''s'       it shows empty records.but in data we have records

Comment: @Malyadri - the whole point is to end up *not* having to double-up or quadruple-up or octuple-up the apostrophes, beyond the original literal input. So, if you've made the top two suggested changes in my answer and made the change to `nvarchar` for `@sql`, you should be executing `exec spCompanyName @CompanyName='So Unique, formerly Sofia''s'`.

Comment: If I execute  exec spCompanyName @CompanyName='So Unique, formerly Sofia''''''''s'  this I need out put. So where should I change above scripts

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to create a new stored procedure for this feature then you can have this in much better way then dynamic.

You should execute different select queries based on if CompanyName is passed or not.

You can simply the stored procedure as following.

```
Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[spCompanyName]              
(              
    @CompanyName VARCHAR(100))
    AS
    Begin
    IF LEN(@CompanyName) > 0               
    BEGIN
        Select EmpID,CompanyName FROM Employee WHERE RTRIM(LTRIM(CompanyName)) like '' + @CompanyName + '%'
    END 
ELSE
BEGIN
        Select EmpID,CompanyName FROM Employee
    END
END
```

I am not sure why you need to pass so many single quotes in the parameter value but to me it looks like you can execute the procedure with following simple way.

```
EXEC spCompanyName @CompanyName='So Unique, formerly Sofia''s'
EXEC spCompanyName @CompanyName='Absolute''s,Strategy''s'
```

This should help you finding your solution.